# "error": "ACCESS DENIED" in postman when I'm running the code I'm using MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

[Picture of error in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYXSk.png)
//This is route

```
router.get("/all/posts",isSignedIn,isAuthenticated, getAllPosts)
```

//This is controller

```
exports.getAllPosts = (req, res) => {
Post.find()
.populate("postedBy","_id username")
.exec((err, posts) => {
if(err || !posts){
  return res.status(400).json({
    error:"No Post found"
  })
}
res.json(posts)
})
}
```

//This is Auth controller which is middleware where I'm getting error

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
let checker = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;
if (!checker) {
console.log(checker);
return res.status(403).json({
  error: "ACCESS DENIED",
  
});
}
 console.log(checker);
next();
};
```

//This is isSignedIn controller

```
//protected routes
  exports.isSignedIn = expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
   userProperty: "auth",
    });
```

//This is signin controller

```
exports.signin = (req, res) => {
 const errors = validationResult(req);
 const { username, password } = req.body;

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
return res.status(422).json({
  error: errors.array()[0].msg,
});
 }

User.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
if (err || !user) {
  return res.status(400).json({
    error: "USER does not exists",
  });
}

if (!user.autheticate(password)) {
  return res.status(401).json({
    error: "Username and password do not match",
  });
}

//create token
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
//put token in cookie
res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });

//send response to front end
const { _id, username, role } = user;
return res.json({ token, user: { _id, username, role } });
 });
  };
```

//Only all/posts having problem remaining all are working fine even isAuthentication is also working with others routes but in this case it is giving error

Comment: what did console.log(checker) print? what's all these req.profile req.profile._id etc, headers? query? headers are in req.header , query are in req.query, post body are in req.body -> http://expressjs.com/en/api.html find req.query

Comment: it show's error in my vsCode log which is undefined when I'm running the code

Comment: please refer to my link above, you need to use req.query req.body, req.header etc

Comment: let checker = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id; this is used to verify the user I'm using jsonwebtoken

Comment: did you try console.log(req.profile, req.auth, req.auth._id) ? They will be undefined. Your middleware need to get the json token from req.headers.authorization, then you need to decode. Kindly verify those values are working first, before you move on to next step.

Comment: yes I have verified this when I'm signing in postman I get a token which I have to put on headers after that I can do my token is working correctly because for other things I can do things easily without interruption

Comment: if it's defined, then it won't return the error, since that's your condition check. Hence, you need to trouble shoot all your req.* which I don't think it's defined. You need to console.log them and make sure they are the correct values. Not with POSTMAN, you need to console.log them on your server side. Otherwise, share what you have for your isSignedIn middleware.

Comment: done i have add the code if you need more info https://github.com/themak01/blog-backend you can get the project from the github

Comment: /all/posts vs /all/users/posts/ - your mistake or intentional?

Comment: earlier it was all/users/posts/ but then I change to all/posts so that every one can see the posts